# RibbonApplicationMenu Recent list

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, ribbon, recent-file-list

I have an .net 4.5 WPF application which automatically (not extra coded) creates recent entries to the JumpList in taskbar. I would like to bind these JumpList items to the RibbonApplicationMenu. I tried to get the current JumpList like this:

```
this.JumpList = JumpList.GetJumpList(App.Current);
```

but I'm not able to bind the List to the RibbonApplicationMenu.

```
                   <RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                    <RibbonGallery CanUserFilter="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                        <RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Recent Documents" Background="Transparent" >
                            <JumpList JumpList="{Binding JumpList}"/>
                        </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    </RibbonGallery>
                </RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
```

What can I do to get a recent list into my RibbonApplicationMenu without creating my own List.

EDIT

I'm doing this in my MainWpf constructor.

```
        JumpList pJumpList = JumpList.GetJumpList(Application.Current);
        pJumpList.ShowFrequentCategory = false;
        pJumpList.ShowRecentCategory = true;

        foreach (var item in this.pJumpList.JumpItems)
        {
            JumpPath path = item as JumpPath;
            this.JumpListCollection.Add(path.Path);
        }
```

I would like to the current recent item from the Jumplist in the RibbonMenu

[image]
[image]

This recent items are created by Windows not from code in my application

Answer (score 0):

In the above code JumpList control doesnot have property to hold the list. Refer the below code. I have used a RibbonGallery.

```
 <Ribbon>
    <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonApplicationMenu Label="test">
            <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Test" />
            <RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                <RibbonGallery CanUserFilter="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding JumpListMyApp}">                        
                </RibbonGallery>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
        </RibbonApplicationMenu>
    </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
</Ribbon>
class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> myVar=new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> JumpListMyApp
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }        

    public ViewModel()
    {
        var jump = JumpList.GetJumpList(App.Current);
        foreach (var item in JumpList.GetJumpList(App.Current).JumpItems)
        {
            JumpTask tsk = item as JumpTask;
            JumpListMyApp.Add(tsk.Description);
        }

    }
}
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        JumpTask task = new JumpTask
        {
            Title = "Check for Updates",
            Arguments = "/update",
            Description = "Cheks for Software Updates",
            CustomCategory = "Actions",
            IconResourcePath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase,
            ApplicationPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase
        };

        JumpList jumpList = new JumpList();
        jumpList.JumpItems.Add(task);
        jumpList.ShowFrequentCategory = false;
        jumpList.ShowRecentCategory = false;

        JumpList.SetJumpList(Application.Current, jumpList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but this does not work for me. It looks like I don't get the current JumpList. Because I always get a null exception. But in the taskbar I can see JumpItems.

Comment: Can you share the Jumplist code which you added for the application?

Comment: I found one fault, but I still don't get it working.
I want to get the current not by my self created JumpList.
    `this.JumpList = JumpList.GetJumpList(Application.Current);`
My JumpList is not coded in my application, it is created by Windows7 it self. I do not create a JumpList in the App.cs so I'm not able to post my code. Maybe it's not possible but I would like to try to let Windows create the JumpList it self.

Comment: Are you getting any jumplist for the application? Did you try clicking on the application. Did you do file association for your application?

Comment: Yes file association is done due an installer. No I don't get any JumpList back. I always get "null". When I double click on my file extension, my software gets open and is doing what is has to do. And after I double click on the file extension file, in the Application JumpList in Task bar I can see the JumpPath.

Comment: If you can upload some sample code. I can try to help you.

Comment: I will post it as soon as possible. Thank you